# What is the better way to save process health status at specific interval in redis?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, pm2

I have multi processor instances each with uniq id assigned to it on the single machine. I am currenlty logging the health status in redis storing data against hash (hash=processorId). Below is data in redis

```
p1 | "{'status': '1', 'ts': '12214444'}"

p2 | "{'status': '1', 'ts': '12214466'}"
```

I will have an agent responsible for finding the dead processor one way will be to frequently check in redis whose timestamp is not updated for more than some threshold. After the agent finds the dead processor, its entry will be removed so no task will be assigned to it. 
Any other approach that will be more efficient.

Comment: set your key with ttl (search or redis setex) so that you dont have to check this interval and its gone when the time comes

Comment: @scetiner won't work because agent will be no way be knowing when the key will be gone because it will be set by another process